# Initialize with data while run the django app for the first time

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have an app **Settings** which contains model namely **Season**. Now I want to intitialize **Season** model with dummy data while I run  `python manage.py makemigration Settings` command for the first time.

I don't even know whether it's possible or not, as I'm very new in Django. So if you know any other way to solve my problem then please let me know also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what format is your data?

Comment: Read this on fixtures https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I don't get your question fully. But I just want to let you know that, input file format can be json or anything (If it is serve my purpose)

Comment: If your format is JSON, see the link provided above by @dmitryro.

Comment: @dmitryro I've read this article few days ago, and I can load data from fixture file perfectly but it doesn't serve my purpose. Cause I want to initialize data with makemigration command.

Comment: That isn't what `makemigrations` does.  Why does `loaddata` not suit your needs?